# DeleteItemAsync is not returned the item being deleted

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

[`Container.DeleteItemAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.deleteitemasync) returns an `ItemResponse<T>` that holds a [`Resource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.itemresponse-1.resource) property. This implies that the call will return the document that is actually deleted.

But the `Resource` property is always `null` and the status is set to `NoContent`, so it seems that this call never returns the document that is actually deleted. Why would it return a typed response, when it never returns an instance of the type. Also [this MS blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/enable-content-response-on-write/#do-we-really-need-the-response-content) describes how the response can explicitly be disabled when deleting documents. This also implies that the item should be deleted.

I have checked the database, but the document is actually being deleted. Trying to delete a non-existing document results in a `NotFound` status and raises an exception.

I have also tried setting `EnableContentResponseOnWrite = true`, but this doesn't do anything. I tried Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.14 and v3.19. Both had the same result...

Comment: Seems to be default behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/delete-a-document. This is bad, because I now need to read the document first and delete it afterwards :-(

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is...

Comment: @NoahStahl The `Container.DeleteItemAsync` returns an `ItemResponse<T>` object that holds the resource. The only logical conclusion is that it would contain the deleted document, but it's always `null`.  This [official MS blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/enable-content-response-on-write/#optimizing-our-bandwidth) shows how to explicitly disable this functionality, so it implies that the default is that it returns the deleted document. But it isn't...

Answer (score 3):

The `DeleteItemAsync` return type is a bit misleading given that `ItemResponse<T>` suggests a populated T with the deleted item but is actually null.

Perhaps a clearer approach is to use [`DeleteItemStreamAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.deleteitemstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet) and inspect the response code, like this:

```
using ResponseMessage response = await container.DeleteItemStreamAsync(itemId, new(partitionKey), options);
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
{
    // Success
}
else
{
    // Failed
}
```

Now you avoid exception-throwing overhead, and the code doesn't mislead about content being non-null.

Comment: Seems like it. But it's weird that an official blog article of a MS Cosmos DB engineer implies that it does return the data :-(

Comment: Using `DeleteItemStreamAsync` is even more awkward, because it returns a `ResponseMessage` that should be disposed. Your example should use a `using` for the `response` variable.

Comment: I agree the blog does imply non-null, not sure on intent. Perhaps Matias will weigh in.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed the IDisposable on ResponseMessage before! Good catch.

Comment: I have filed a GitHub issue to improve the documentation on this item: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/21674

Comment: It would probably make more sense in the .NET SDK repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3

Comment: Yeah, it was my bad on including Delete on the blog, that was corrected. Sorry! The blog is corrected and actually updated with a new global option.